# How can I replace session_register and undefined constant

Tags: php, mysql

How can I replace this code to suit with PHP 5.5

```
<?php
    include("dbconnect.php");
    session_start();
    session_register('user');
    session_register('cart');
?>
```

And when I call the `$id` in PHP code with mySQL CusID row by:

```
<?php
                $user=$_SESSION['user'];
                $sql="select *from customer where Cususername='$user'";
                $rs=mysql_query($sql) or die('Cannot select from customer table');
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
                $id=$row[CusID];
                if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
                {
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=dangky'>Đăng ký</a></li>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=dangnhap'>Đăng nhập</a></li>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=quantri'>Quản Trị</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=phanhoi'>Phản hồi</a></li>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=sua'>Chào bạn ".$row["CusName"]."</a></li>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=sua'>Quản lý tài khoản</a>";
                    echo"<ul>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=giohang'>Giỏ hàng của bạn</a></li>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=giaodich'>Giao dịch gần đây</a></li>";
                    echo"<li><a href='?options=thoat'>Đăng xuất</a></li>";
                    echo"</ul>";
                    echo"</li>";
                }
                ?>
```

I got the error

```
Use of undefined constant CusID - assumed 'CusID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

at line `$id=$row[CusID];`

Please explain what happens with >PHP 5.4. I'm a newbie

Comment: Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Yeah, so what I have to do to change it to suit with PHP 5.4

Comment: I would suggest following the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php   Be sure to note where it says the function has been deprecated since 5.3 and the preferred approach available since 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using CusID as a constant. You need to quote it:

```
$id=$row["CusID"];
```

Comment: Still `Use of undefined constant CusID - assumed 'CusID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\`, with the quote '' and ""

Comment: @TuyenNguyen - You updated one place where it's note quoted but not the other.